# What is this notation? Cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

$\mathbb{Z}^*_8$

As I understand it - $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is the group of integers under **addition modulo 8**.

So am I correct in thinking its elements are: $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$?

I thought the $*$ meant *excluding zero*, so I was confused to learn that the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$ are apparently: $\{1,3,5,7\}$ - missing $2$, $4$ and $6$.

The only possible answer I can think of is that because <1>,<3>,<5> and <7> can generate the whole group - $2$, $4$ and $6$ are omitted from $\mathbb{Z}_8$ in the first place, meaning $*$ does just remove the zero as I thought.

Can someone explain this to me as the notes I'm using aren't helping!

Comment: The star removes all the elements that don't have multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Note that $(\Bbb{Z}/8\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is *not* cyclic.

Comment: To make explicit what is implicit in the answers, for this problem it is not correct to think of $\mathbb Z_8$ as the group of integers under addition modulo $8$. Instead, it is better to think of $\mathbb Z_8$ as the **ring** of integers under addition and multiplication modulo $8$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z_8}^*$ denotes the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z_8}$ as Mark Bennet has said.

You can show that $x \in \mathbb{Z_n}$ has a multiplicative inverse if and only if $(x,n)=1$. The proof is based on a special case of  Bezout's theorem that states $(x,n)=1$ if and only if $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: ax+bn = 1$.

If $(x,n)=1$, then $\exists a,b: ax+bn=1$. This implies that $bn = 1-ax$ or $n \mid 1-ax$ which is the same as $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.

On the other hand, if there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z_n}$ such that $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ then $\exists b \in \mathbb{Z}: bn = 1 - ax$. Which gives you the converse.

So, the necessary and sufficient condition for an element in $\mathbb{Z_n}$ to be invertible is that it is relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: I finally understand, thanks to both you and Mark for the quick answers!

Comment: @Jack: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the elements coprime with *n* means those who have no common prime factor with *n*. This means we take only those who have an inverse (and are not zero divisors, which is saying the same thing dealing with finite groups). In the first example with $\mathbb{Z}/8$ , we keep the classes representatives as 1, 3, 5, 7 and make them into a abelian multiplicative group named $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$ . Some use an *, others like Andrew Baker from University of Glasgow use a x. He would write $(\mathbb{Z}/8)^×$. There is a group isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$ and  $\mathbb{Z}/2$ x $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

This shows the isomorphism:

[image]

http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/padicnotes.pdf

Comment: Your last statement is false; the group $(\Bbb{Z}/8\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic. Also, non-zero divisors are not necessarily units in general; in *finite* rings they are though.

Comment: You are right I will correct this isomorphism thing. Also, I was taking into account math.n00b previous post's explanation about coprime and zero divisors. I took into account that we were talking about finite groups. Should have made it clear. Thanks for the fast reaction.

Answer (score 2):

This is a notational device. The $^*$ is being used to show that the group operation is multiplication, and the elements of the group are the elements of $\mathbb Z_8$ which are coprime to $8$. The identity is $1$.

The integers taken modulo $n$ inherit both addition and multiplication from $\mathbb Z$. If you take the elements coprime to $n$ you get a multiplicative group of order $\varphi (n)$ whose elements satisfy $$x^{\varphi(n)}=1$$This is the [Euler-Fermat theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), a generalisation of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure the notation is entirely standard, but if you try making a multiplicative group including even numbers you find that $2\times 4=4\times 4=6\times 4=0$ - they have no inverses. To get a multiplicative group you have to eliminate numbers which have a common factor with $n$ - these are zero-divisors (the trivial exception is that $0$ forms a one element multiplicative group).

Answer (score 1):

The $^*$ only means "excluding zero" when you have a field $\Bbb F$:  in that case the nonzero elements form a group under multiplication.

In the (more general) case of a ring $\mathcal R$, the group of units (invertible elements under multiplication)  can be denoted by $\mathcal R^*,\mathcal R^×$ or $U(\mathcal R)$.  Sometimes you see $U(n)$ or $U_n$.

So, since $\Bbb Z_8$ is a ring, but not a field,  $\Bbb Z_8^*$ refers to the $\varphi (8)=4$ elements of $\Bbb Z_8$ invertible under multiplication.  (Here $\varphi $ is Euler's totient function).   Namely, those that are relatively prime to $8$.

Gauß knew that $\Bbb Z_n^*$ is cyclic when (and only when)  $n=1,2,4$, a power of an odd prime,  or $2$ times a power of an odd prime.

Thus, $\Bbb Z_8^*$ is not cyclic. Since its order is $4$, and it's abelian, it follows that it's isomorphic to the *Klein four group*.